# I created a new column in an existing table, now I want to group dates into that column

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to group dates that fall within a particular range as week 4, week 5 .... and I want to have it in the new column I created in the table

Comment: Please elaborate the question with data and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I had an existing table with client's details, like, name, id number, date profile was created, etc, I created a weeks column into the data table by editing the schema, now I want to group the 'date profile was created' into weeks, for instance if the profile was created between 3rd and 7th of January, I want it grouped as week1 and I want this week1 to appear in the weeks column I created

Comment: `EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date_profile_created)` will return a week number of the year.